# MVC and DropdownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to include a drop down list of my object (read from database) across my webpage.

This is my object:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string fileName { get; set; }

    public string browser { get; set; }

    public string protocol { get; set; }

    public string family { get; set; }
}
```

My controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<MyObject> list = db.MyObjects.Where(x => x.family == "Web").ToList();
    ViewBag.Files = lList;
    return View();
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApplication.Models.MyObject>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";    
}
```

Don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: If you can provide some example data then it will helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<MyObject> list = db.MyObjects.Where(x => x.family == "Web").ToList();
    ViewBag.Files =new SelectList(list,"Id","fileName)";
    return View();
}
```

Add in the view

```
  @Html.DropDownList("File",new SelectList(ViewBag.Files))
```

Comment: Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object, can't understand why

Comment: Edit: Ok, works fine, but if i want to show inside my DropdownList only specific of myObject property ? (and of course avoid duplicate if there is)

Comment: you may try DistinctBy

Comment: in controller, as it is more appropriate.

Comment: But this property is string and i want to return my object but only show this on dropdownlist

Comment: The current solution is show on my DropDownListItem System.Web.Mvc.SelectList instead of my Object property

Comment: @user979033: This worked for me: `@Html.DropDownList("File", ViewBag.Files as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)`

Comment: or rather `@Html.DropDownList("File", ViewBag.Files as SelectList)`